# How to only get the model #, but it is within multiple in line <li> tags HTML webscraping

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
<ul class="item-features">
                <li><strong>Max Resolution:</strong> 7680 x 4320</li>
                <li><strong>DisplayPort:</strong> 3 x DisplayPort 1.4</li>
                <li><strong>HDMI:</strong> 1 x HDMI 2.1</li>
                <li><strong>Card Dimensions (L x H):</strong> 9.13" x 4.88"</li>
                <li><strong>Model #: </strong>RTX3060TiVENTUS2XOC</li>
                <li><strong>Item #: </strong>N82E16814137612</li>
                <li><strong>Return Policy: </strong><a href="https://kb.newegg.com/Article/Index/12/3?id=1167#54" target="_blank" title="Extended Holiday Replacement-Only Return Policy(New Window)">Extended Holiday Replacement-Only Return Policy</a></li>
            </ul>
```

As you can see there are multiple in-line li tags.
How would I go about just extracting the Model #?

I have tried accessing via index:

```
containers = page_soup.findAll("ul",{"class":"item-features"})
containers.li[4]
```

But that errors out.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use find all and then get the required item

```
containers = soup.findAll("ul",{"class":"item-features"})
containers[0].find_all('li')[4].text
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find child with index 4:

```
container = page_soup.find("ul",{"class":"item-features"})
model = container.findChildren('li')[4]
```